# Gradle: how to get user input

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm currently using the Gradle Plugin for Eclipse (STS). I'm trying to get some user input to configure a task. With the daemon, there are problems to read user input. So, I tried to use a Groovy Pop up.

I've got one task which is call to build and show the pop up.

```
task getUserInfo << {
    def sb = new SwingBuilder()
    sb.frame(title: 'Info',
             location: [400, 50],
             pack: true,
             show: true,
             defaultCloseOperation: JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
      gridLayout(columns: 2, rows: 4)
      label('First name:')
      textField(id: 'firstName')       

      label('Last name:')
      textField(id: 'lastName')

      button(text: 'Enter', actionPerformed: {
        myGlobalVariable = "info: ${firstName.text} ${lastName.text}"
    }
```

Also, I create another task: 
`task deploy(dependsOn: getUserInput) { doLast {...} }`. In this task, I try to read the global variable containing the result of the user input.
**But the problem is that Gradle continue to the deploy task without waiting for my input.**

**How can I fix that to read user input before doing other tasks?**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try this example from Tim Roes. https://www.timroes.de/2014/01/19/using-password-prompts-with-gradle-build-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really a Swing question, namely how to create a *modal* dialog. [Getting the User's Input from a Dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) has an example.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I changed this to a modal dialog and now its works perfectly. Thank you for your help